# How can I make onEdit trigger not to fire on border style change?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, formatting

I noticed that messing around with the text style and formatting will not make onEdit triggers fire.
However, messing around with cells' borders will.

Why is that? Is there a clever workaround to make an onEdit trigger fire only upon actual content changes?

Thanks!

Comment: That’s interesting I would have guessed that it would not have fired for cell border changes but I guess it is a user edit to a cell. I wonder if you can check to see if e.oldValue==e.value

Comment: Hi @Cooper. Yes, I tried this approach - e.oldValue will be _`undefined`_ in these cases: 1. Editted range is not a single cell; 2. Editted cell was empty before the edit` 3. Editted cell's value was not changed; 4. no action that's considered as `edit` was made (for example - changing text style). Hence, this approach works only for content changes where a single cell had some value and this value was replaced with another

Comment: Will be happy to hear more ideas, as the provided answer did not provide a solution

Comment: I’m kind of interested in this I’ll set up an example for myself and play with it and see if I can come up with a solution for you

Comment: I find that you're correct it seems that content changes and border changes are only things that cause the onedit trigger to fire.  But I guess the question is how does this cause any problems for you.  What is that you wish to do that this feature prevents you from doing?

Comment: I'm trying to mark with a purple double border single cells upon content change. I also want the user to be able to manually "reset" the borders of these cells to a black single border, without the script re-changing them as a result.

Comment: Well perhaps you want to use the background instead of the border

Comment: I would, except the background is already an indication for something else in my data O_O, and also text styling

Comment: There a lot of different colors.  But  it doesn't matter there is no work around as far a I know.

Answer (score 0):

The `onEdit` trigger **will fire** if the text style is edited as well as if the formatting is edited. The same behavior goes if the cell borders are being edited. Basically, if the sheet is being edited, the `onEdit` trigger will work.

In order to make it work strictly for value changes you can try this snippet:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var oldval = e.oldValue;
  var newval = e.range.getValue();
  if (oldval != newval) 
    console.log("a change has been made to the value")
  else 
    console.log("a change hasn't been made to the value");
}
```

Also, please note that as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) the `oldValue` will only work for one cell - so if you plan on editing multiple cells at the same time and check for their values, it won't work.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Comment: Thanks, @ale13, except it's not correct. You are welcome to try and see that it does not fire upon text styling.

Comment: Adding my comment to @Cooper (above) here too: "`e.oldValue` will be _`undefined`_ in these cases: 1. Editted range is not a single cell; 2. Editted cell was empty before the edit` 3. Editted cell's value was not changed; 4. no action that's considered as `edit` was made (for example - changing text style). Hence, this approach works only for content changes where a single cell had some value and this value was replaced with"

Comment: I see what you mean, so sorry if I was a bit harsh with my response. **I'll clarify** - when you manually select the text in a cell - the trigger work. *However*, if you select a single cell, without selecting the actual text, and change the text style / font / size / color - the trigger will not fire.

Comment: @YanivAflalo, it does trigger. If the style of the text in a cell was changed (click the cell, ctr+A to select the text, change the style to italic for example), the trigger was triggered. If multiple cells are in the range, just like I mentioned, there's nothing you can do about it in order to check.

Comment: @YanivAflalo, " if you select a single cell, without selecting the actual text, and change the text style / font / size / color - the trigger will not fire" that's true. But if you want to trigger an action based on simply selecting a cell for example, you can make use of the `onSelectionChange` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). But there's no way to not make the `onEdit` trigger trigger when the style of the border changes for multiple cells in the range.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is an `onEdit` trigger that will not fire on any kind of styling change, so the `onSelectionChange` trigger is more sensitive, instead of less compared with the `onEdit`.

Comment: @YanivAflalo ... We don't have any control over what causes the trigger to fire.  We are simply given the ability to react to it.

Comment: I know we don't, but we have ways to manipulate the function to cease from running upon certain conditions. I'm in the search for the right condition for this case. That is what I mean by "Not fire" (it will fire, but stop before doing any action)

Comment: @YanivAflalo, There's no way to manipulate the trigger in such a way that it **does not** trigger when a specific action is done - especially when working with a range of cells and not just a particular cell for which you can check its value. Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 There is always a way, I just need to find it. I don't mind the function to be called, just want it to not do anything in a given scenario.Thanks for your time and effort :)